# Include an array in another array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Was wondering how to add the values of one array into another to save me typing the values of one array over and over:

```
$array_main = array(
    '[1]' => '1',
    '[2]' => '2',
    '[3]' => '3',
    '[4]' => '4'
);

$array_1 = array( $array_main, '[5]' => '5' );
```

This deduces:

```
$array_1 = array(
    array(
        '[1]' => '1',
        '[2]' => '2',
        '[3]' => '3',
        '[4]' => '4'
    ),
    '[5]' => '5'
);
```

But I wanted:

```
$array_1 = array(
    '[1]' => '1',
    '[2]' => '2',
    '[3]' => '3',
    '[4]' => '4',
    '[5]' => '5'
);
```

So is there anything that can turn an array into a string? I've tried `implode` and `array_shift` but I need the whole `array()` not just the values..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>

The above example will output:

Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Yep! Knew there was something so simple I overlooked!

Comment: It would be faster if you just copy the array to a new variable, and assign a new value to it with `[]` like @Rikesh mentioned (in his original answer lol)

Comment: I agree with @OneTrickPony that Rikesh's method would be quicker, but this answer is most comprehensive (of what is available at this moment) and best originally answered. This is my reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

Fastest way is simply use single array like following,

```
$array_main = array(
    '[1]' => '1',
    '[2]' => '2',
    '[3]' => '3',
    '[4]' => '4'
);
$array1 = $array_main;
$array1['[5]'] = '5';
```

Though if specific requirement for new array use [**array_merge**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php),

```
$array1 = array_merge($array_main,array('[5]' => '5'));
```

Comment: Thanks !! @one Trick Pony.

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge array (don't just want to add an extra value) to merge two arrays:

```
<?php
    $array1 = array("0" => "0", "1" => "1");
    $array2 = array("a" => "a", "b" => "b");
    print_r( array_merge($array1, $array2 );
?>
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [a] => a
    [b] => b
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge()`

```
$array_1 = array_merge($array_main, array('[5]' => '5'));
```